# Anybody knows how to export in Java data from google app engine datastore to fusion tables ?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, datastore, google-fusion-tables

A Java library ?
Something like datastore2FusionTable(kind) -> id of fusion table

Comment: You mean google fusion tables, right?

Answer (score 1):

There's no existing library for this, as far as I'm aware. You'll have to write your own.